# Interior points of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any  unbounded set $X$ of points in $\mathbb R$ that satisfies that the set of interior points of $X$ is $(-1,1)$? How to give such an example?

Comment: By (-1,1) you mean -1 and 1 or the interval (-1,1)?

Comment: open interval (-1,1)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest one I can think of: $(-1,1) \cup \textbf{Z}$

Answer (score 1):

One example:

$$(-1,1)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}. $$